# Cassandra / Hector = Is there a function to jump to a position in the index?

Tags: nosql, cassandra, hector

does Cassandra/Hector provide a method, that supports "jumping" (=accessing) a specific position in an Index for both and:

> ((Rows))

and

> Columns

I know of tombstones... I would not mind... (they can be included in the results/calculation)

IMPORTANT: I know that Rows are distributed over a lot of machines. So the question applies mainly to Columns (that reside on one machine).

I am looking for use cases like "Give me the "Record=((Row))/Column" that is exaclty in the middle of the index... Or give me the "Record=((Row))/Column" that is at Position 454654. Both for Rows and for Columns.

Is this somehow supported like `getColumAtIndexPosition(int index)` ? If not, why not? Wouldn't it be easy to just internally count the index records up to the correct position in Cassandra an return the rsult?

Thanks very much!
Jens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't such a function.

Hector is a layer over the [Cassandra api](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/API).  For retrieving columns, the Cassandra api method that comes closest to what you want is get_slice, which allows you to perform queries such as get the first N columns where column name is > X, or all the columns whose name is between X and Y, but not the 500'th column.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I am already using Hector. Just for all who are reading this (and evaluating cassandra): Paging is a lot of overhead and much more complicated than in MySQL due to the lack of this. And theres no possiblity to say give me the "median value" in the middle. This is a real disadvantage. Thanks for your answer.